# Web Sockets and Dynamics CRM

Tags: websocket, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, webhooks, dynamics-365

1. Is it possible to do a Web Hook subscribe with Dynamics CRM?
   Eg: Have an external application, which should be able to push changes into DynamicsCRM (like, update of a record), when the external application undergoes a change.
2. Is it possible to use WebSockets in Dynamics CRM?
   Can I force my CRM server to cause a change in the CRM UI, to maybe, show an alert message / redirect the form?

Thanks in advance!
Reposted from https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/282877

Answer (score 2):

1. No. CRM can make Web Hook requests out, but cannot accept Web Hook requests. You'd need something like an [Azure function with a Web Hook binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook) in the middle where the external application makes a request to the function and the function makes a request to CRM.
2. No. If you are using CRM on-premises you could build something custom but this isn't built into the platform.

Comment: You are right. The platform allows to make WebHook requests, but have to use some service like an Azure function to communicate back from the external application to the Dynamics platform.